# Binding input selection to dropdown Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi I have following input

`<input type="text" class="form-controlb" ng-model="item.name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" /`>

And following dropdown

```
                <div class="col-sm-12" ng-model="query">
                    <select ng-model="item" class="form-control" ng-options="a.name for a in addemployees | filter:name | orderBy:'name'" value="{{a.name}}">
                        <option value="">[Select Employee..]</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
```

Basically what I am trying to do is, when I enter name in the input box if dropdown has that name ints options to show it in dropdown.
I tried to do do filter by name and than orderby name but it doesnt show any on dropdown as selection. 
Please let me know how to fix it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this may work:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="text" />
<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="option.name for option in options">
</select>

$scope.options = [{
  name: 'a',
  value: 'value-a'
}, {
  name: 'b',
  value: 'value-b'
}];

$scope.selectedOption = $scope.options[0];

$scope.$watch('text', function(v) {
  for (var i in $scope.options) {
    var option = $scope.options[i];
    if (option.name === v) {
      $scope.selectedOption = option;
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Lj0p3wig9JfOM0UkpDrd

Answer (score 1):

[plank](http://plnkr.co/edit/stDVowlSq7e5wUw5YwHN?p=preview)

I hope my example will be useful -)

```
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Search :</td>
        <td><input ng-model="query[queryBy]" /></td>
    </tr>           
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Search By :</td>
        <td>
            <select ng-model="queryBy">
                <option value="$"></option>
                <option value="name">NAME</option>
                <option value="company">COMPANY</option>
                <option value="designation">DESIGNATION</option>
            </select>   
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

ng-repeat:

```
            <tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees | filter:query">
            <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.company}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.designation}}</td>
        </tr>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('module3', [])
.controller('testCtrl3', function($scope){
$scope.query = {}
$scope.queryBy = '$'
$scope.items = [
  {
    "name" : "Ananchenko Juriy",
    "company" : "GOOGLE. Ltd",
    "designation" : "Creativ Director"
  },
  {
    "name" : "Ananchenko",
    "company" : "GOOGLE"
  },
  {
    "name" : "Korman Juriy",
    "company" : "GOOGLE. Ltd",
    "designation" : "stager na ispitatelnom sroke"
  }
];
$scope.orderProp="name";
```

});